# Java Spring populating bidirectional relationship

Tags: java, spring, one-to-many

Consider I have something like this:

```
public class ClassifierGroupEntity extends AbstractEntity{
...
@OneToMany (mappedBy = "parent",
                fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
                cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<ClassifierEntity> classifiers;
...
}
```

--

```
public class ClassifierEntity extends AbstractEntity {
...
    @ManyToOne
    private ClassifierGroupEntity parent;
...
}
```

If I want to add a new classifier to a group, how should I go about it? Is this ok?:

```
ClassifierGroupEntity ge = new ClassifierGroupEntity();
manager.saveClassifierGroup(ge);
ClassifierEntity e = new ClassifierEntity();
e.setParent(ge);
manager.saveClassifier(e);
```

Comment: Yeah. It's OK. `ClassifierEntity`  has a dependency to `ClassifierGroupEntity` as its parent, so first you should save instance of `ClassifierGroupEntity` then an instance of `ClassifierEntity`. However, you can save them at once I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach will work at the basic level. I prefer the following paradigm (ignore the class names):

```
package org.example.project.domain;

@Entity
class Classifier {
  @ManyToOne
  private ClassifierGroup group;

  public ClassifierGroup getGroup() { return group; }

  // Package protected to prevent direct access.
  void setGroup(ClassifierGroup group) { this.group = group; }
}

@Entity
class ClassifierGroup {
  @OneToMany
  private List<Classifier> classifiers;

  public void addClassifier(Classifier classifier) {
    if(classifiers == null) {
      classifiers = new ArrayList<Classifier>();
    }

    classifiers.add(classifier);
    classifier.setGroup(this);
  }

  public List<Classifier> getClassifiers() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(classifiers != null ? classifiers : Collections.emptyList());
  }
}

ClassifierGroup group = new ClassifierGroup();
group.addClassifier(new Classifier());
manager.saveClassifierGroup(group);
```

Or better still, if `group` is mandatory for a `Classifier`, set it in the constructor itself (`public Classifier(ClassifierGroup group)`).

This strategy has the following key features:

1. The relationships are managed by the entities themselves. Outside parties do not need to know the details of the relationships. This comes in handy if objects can be instantiated in more than one place, in which case the relationship management code may potentially have to be duplicated across the codebase.
2. Direct access to data is prevented (only getters, no setters). Therefore, a consumer cannot do `group.getClassifiers().clear()` or `classifier.setGroup(null)`, potentially corrupting the object graph.